# Load local html file in webbrowser control in editable mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to load a local html file in webbrowser control in *editable* mode. My code for loading in html file in webBrowser is:

```
private void LoadFile(string filename)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
    {
       webBrowser1.DocumentText = reader.ReadToEnd();
       reader.Close();
       Text = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle;
    }
}
```

But it is not editable.

Comment: What do you mean with **editable mode**? Do you wand to change the html code within your webBrowser Control?

Comment: yes, i want to edit in html code within browser and i did it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this snippet.

```
 webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(@"D:\TEMP\sample.htm");
```